# preg_match find a link

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
http://example.com/codeThatIHave?killcode=codeIWant
```

How do I get the code I want using preg_match

tried this

```
preg_match_all("#killcode=([^=<]+)<#", $page, $del)
```

but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
preg_match_all("#\?.+?=([^\s]+)#i",$page,$del)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `preg_match` if I were you. PHP has a couple of useful functions that do exactly what you need/want: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url), which parses a url string into its various components, and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str), which breaks down a URI into an assoc array of key-value pairs:

```
$parsed = parse_url('http://example.com/codeThatIHave?killcode=codeIWant');//parse url into assoc array
parse_str($parsed['query'], $vars);//parse query string into assoc array
var_dump($vars);
var_dump($vars['killcode']);//get get param
```

## [Demo](https://eval.in/497169)